# Translating regex into LIKE statements for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a regular expression that I have been using in Postgres that I want to translate to SQL Server, but I believe SQL Server lacks the full capabilities of using regular expressions. However, I think my regular expression should be simple enough to translate into `LIKE` statements.

This is my regular expression: `^[123ABC]*([456])`. From my understanding of regular expressions, the two features that I'm using here are the ability to match zero-or-more characters at the beginning of the string and capture groups.

Here's an example using Postgres:

```sql
CREATE TABLE inventory (id INT, pcode VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (1, 'AABC547');
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (2, '656ABC49');
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (3, '11AB727');
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES (4, '7712346');

SELECT
    id,
    pcode,
    COALESCE(
        SUBSTRING(pcode from '^[123ABC]*([456])'):: int, 0
    ) AS desired_val
FROM inventory;

-- id   pcode    desired_val
-- 1    AABC547  5
-- 2    656ABC49 6
-- 3    11AB727  0
-- 4    7712346  0
```

Here's my attempt to try to rewrite this for use with SQL Server which gets the first row wrong because I am not getting the first value that matches my desired pattern `[456]`, but the last one.

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    pcode,
    CASE
        WHEN pcode LIKE '[456]%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(pcode, 1, 1) AS INT)
        WHEN pcode LIKE '[123ABC]%4%' THEN 4
        WHEN pcode LIKE '[123ABC]%5%' THEN 5
        WHEN pcode LIKE '[123ABC]%6%' THEN 6
        ELSE 0
    END AS desired_val
FROM inventory;

-- id   pcode    desired_val
-- 1    AABC547  4
-- 2    656ABC49 6
-- 3    11AB727  0
-- 4    7712346  0
```

Comment: You have `[123ABC]%4%` repeated 3 times.

Comment: Good catch! I've corrected that typo, but the fundamental issue remains.

Comment: Yeah, in this _specific_ case, it will return the correct values, but it's not equivalent to the regex pattern. As far as I know, there's no way to say "zero or more of a specific character" using `LIKE`, so I'm not sure how to come up with an equivalent.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, even with the correction, I still get the wrong value for the first row. Perhaps creative use of `REVERSE` might help?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex at all; it's not a case of that it supports *some* of it. If you *have* to implement Regex on SQL Server, you'll need to implement CLR objects.

Comment: @vikjam Yeah, you're right. I really don't think you can achieve that with pure T-SQL.

Comment: There might be a way to do this if the `[123ABC]` part consists of a fixed number of characters (or maybe if it has 2 or 3 possibilities). Otherwise, I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, perhaps something like `LIKE '[123ABC]%' OR LIKE '[123ABC][123ABC]%' OR LIKE '[123ABC][123ABC][123ABC]%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really have to do this with pure T-SQL, you may write something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  pcode,
  CASE
    WHEN pcode LIKE '[456]%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(pcode, 1, 1) AS INT)
    WHEN pcode LIKE REPLICATE('[123ABC]', CHARINDEX('4', pcode) - 1) + '4%' THEN 4
    WHEN pcode LIKE REPLICATE('[123ABC]', CHARINDEX('5', pcode) - 1) + '5%' THEN 5
    WHEN pcode LIKE REPLICATE('[123ABC]', CHARINDEX('6', pcode) - 1) + '6%' THEN 6
    ELSE 0
  END AS desired_val
FROM inventory;
```

The trick is to use `CHARINDEX()` to get the position of the first occurrence of a `[456]` char, and then use `REPLICATE()` to repeat the `[123ABC]` pattern a number of times equal to the number of characters that precede the desired character. So, in the first example, where the `'5'` char is found at the fifth position, the constructed pattern will be:

```
[123ABC][123ABC][123ABC][123ABC]5%
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution:

```
create table #inventory(id int identity,pcode varchar(10))
insert into #inventory values ('AABC547')
insert into #inventory values ('656ABC49')
insert into #inventory values ('11AB727')
insert into #inventory values ('7712346')

SELECT
  id,
  pcode,
  CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pcode,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'A',''),'B',''),'C','') LIKE '[456]%'
    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(pcode,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'A',''),'B',''),'C',''), 1, 1) AS INT)
    ELSE 0
  END AS desired_val
FROM #inventory;

drop table #inventory
```

This solution removes the allowed leading characters from the pcode. These REPLACEs will remove all occurrences. So this only works if there is no overlap between these leading characters ("123ABC") and the characters you are searching ("456").